# How to avoid the first render of a component while refreshing a page when filtering data based on query strings?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js

I have a table component:

```
import { useState, useEffect, useRef } from 'react';
import data from '@/data.json';
import { useRouter } from 'next/router'

import styles from './table.module.css';

export default function Table() {
  const firstUpdate = useRef(true);
  let [tableDate, updateTableDate] = useState([]);

  const router = useRouter();
  
  useEffect(() => {
    if (firstUpdate.current) {
      firstUpdate.current = false;
      return;
    }

    updateTableDate(() => {
      const result = router.query.search ? data.filter((item) => item.title.toLowerCase().match(router.query.search.toLowerCase())) : data;
      return result;
    });    
  }, [router.query.search]);
  
  return (
    <>
      <div className={styles.table}>
        <table>
          <thead>
            <tr>
              <th>
                Title
              </th>           
            </tr>
          </thead>
          <tbody>
            {tableDate.map((item, i) =>
              <tr key={item.id}>
                <td>
                   {item.title}            
                </td>
              </tr>
            )}
          </tbody>
        </table>
      </div>
    </>
  );
}
```

I have a table and an input for a search query.
The table is rendered like this:

- If the search query is empty, or I just went to the results page, then I will see all data;
- If I enter something in the search - data will be filtered based on the search query string.

The problem occurs under the following conditions:
I entered a search query, the table was rebuilt, and then I reload the page.
At this moment, I see first how all the data is drawn, and only after the table with filtered data. How to avoid it?

Comment: Why not just add a loading spinner state. 
if (!loaded) {
    return <div>Loading...</div>;
  }

Comment: I would like to do without spinner.

Comment: You can check [`router.isReady`](https://nextjs.org/docs/pages/api-reference/functions/use-router#router-object) in your `useEffect` and return early (above the `const result = ...` if `!router.isReady`, then return empty data or whatever elements you want depending on that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are getting the full data first, and then it's getting filtered because it takes some time to run JavaScript on the client to get the query string and re-render the component.

You could change your `useEffect` as below. You update the data only when the router is ready and show nothing (or a loader) as long as `tableDate` is empty.

```
import { useState, useEffect, useRef } from 'react';
import data from '@/data.json';
import { useRouter } from 'next/router'

import styles from './table.module.css';

export default function Table() {
  let [tableDate, updateTableDate] = useState([]);

  const router = useRouter();

  useEffect(() => {
    updateTableDate(() => {
      if (!router.isReady) {
        return [];
      }
      const result = router.query.search
        ? data.filter((item) => item.title.toLowerCase().match(router.query.search.toLowerCase()))
        : data;
      return result;
    });
  }, [router]);

  if (tableDate.length <= 0) {
    // You could return a loading spinner if you want
    return null;
  }

  return <>Render your table</>;
}
```